# Do loop with condition - segmentation fault

Tags: arrays, segmentation-fault, fortran

I am doing a project on particle dynamics and I started by letting a particle (a sphere) fall from a certain height towards a fixed particle in the ground.

Inside a do loop (a time loop, from the initial time to a certain time elapsed with a certain time-step), I use an Euler's method to integrate the positions and velocities, and also calculate the forces (gravitational and elastic) and the collision conditions as well.

This model will later be generalized for 3, 4, ..., n particles (in the scale of hundreds of thousands), and so I am using arrays to punctuate the particles which positions and velocities as time goes by I am integrating. That way, I also put a do loop inside the time loop - for each particle - from 1 to N (the number of particles), and define N as 2 (since in this case alone I have only two particles). This is the segmentation fault, since I tell it to calculate 3 things when I only specified that I have two.

Whilst trying to fix it, when I define the parameters for i and i+1, when i=2, i+1 = 2+1 = 3 will be calculated - but I do not have a third particle. In a similar way, if I put i-1 and i instead, for i = 1 (where the loop starts), i-1 = 0, but that doesn't make sense, since I do not have a "0th" particle. In another attempt, if I change the loop from 1,N to 1,N-1, since N=1, it won't calculate for N=2. Also, I have thought about printing my results in twos, that is, for particles 1 and 2, 2 and 3, 3 and 4, and so on... (calculating i AND i+1 simultaneously for each integration, making the run time longer - which will cost me a lot of time later, since these simulations for a big number of particles can take weeks). But if I state that in files, it will repeat the file creation for all particles, except for the first and the last (even more time wasted). How can I run it only considering the first and two particles, generalizing for any number of particles that I choose?

```
do t = tmin, tmax, dt
    do i = 1,N
        call contact (xold(i), xold(i+1), r(i), r(i+1))
        call forces (m(i),  g, k, r(i), r(i+1), xold(i), xold(i+1))
        call euler(xold(i), xnew(i), vold(i), vnew(i), dt, F(i), m(i))
        write(i, *), "t=", t, "x=", xold(i), "v=", vold(i), "dx=", dx, "force=", F(i)
    end do
end do
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not quite sure, what exactly you would like to achieve. For a particle simulation, where each particle interacts with each other particle you would need to have a second loop, wouldn't you?
Somewhat like this:

```
do i = 1,N
   do j=i+1,N
    call contact (xold(i), xold(j), r(i), r(j))
    call forces (m(i),  g, k, r(i), r(j), xold(i), xold(j))
   end do

   call euler(xold(i), xnew(i), vold(i), vnew(i), dt, F(i), m(i))
   write(i, *), "t=", t, "x=", xold(i), "v=", vold(i), "dx=", dx, "force=", F(i)

end do
```

The inner loop will not be executed if `i+1 > N`, so everything should be fine. For N=2 you would just get one execution with `i=1` and `j=2`.

**Edit:**

> calculating i AND i+1 simultaneously for each integration, making the run time longer - which will cost me a lot of time later, since these simulations for a big number of particles can take weeks

You most likely do *not* want to do a all-to-all particle simulation for large numbers of particles. Most people use some tree algorithms to speed this up considerably. Consider using an existing Framework for that, like [PEPC](http://www.fz-juelich.de/ias/jsc/EN/AboutUs/Organisation/ComputationalScience/Simlabs/slpp/SoftwarePEPC/_node.html).

Answer (score 0):

> when i=2, i+1 = 2+1 = 3 will be calculated - but I do not have a third
>   particle. In a similar way, if I put i-1 and i instead, for i = 1
>   (where the loop starts), i-1 = 0, but that doesn't make sense, since I
>   do not have a "0th" particle

Modulo?

```
when i = 0, i % 2 = 0, (i % 2) + 1 = 1
when i = 1, i % 2 = 1, (i % 2) + 1 = 2
when i = 2, i % 2 = 0, (i % 2) + 1 = 1
when i = 3, i % 2 = 1, (i % 2) + 1 = 2
```